# Run matlab compiled dll library from a C program on Linux/OSX

Tags: c++, c, linux, macos, matlab

So I have a `.dll` file that was built via Matlab on Windows and I would like to run it on a C/C++ program I've created. Is that possible at all?

I know I can run it on windows like this:

```
#include <windows.h>
...
HINSTANCE hinstLib;
hinstLib = LoadLibrary(TEXT("MyPuts.dll"));
...
```

But `windows.h` is not available on Linux/OSX, is there any other way?

Alternatively is there any other format I can build the Matlab library in? Maybe `.so` is that an option?

Comment: `.so` file is **THE** solution. DLL cannot be used in Linux environment.

Comment: I don't think that's possible. If you want to use it in a Linux/OSX context you have to compile your code into a shared object `MyPuts.so` or similar in order to run it from a C or C++ program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do think that would be problamatic. As the Wauzl comment suggest you should compile it to .so if possible. Another option would be to run the entire program compiled for windows under wine.

I havent checked out winelib myself, but maybe it might be worth a look 
[Winelib guide](https://www.winehq.org/docs/winelib-guide/index)

> Winelib is a development toolkit which allows you to compile your Windows applications on Unix.